# Find all elasticsearch documents with a field that is an array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with a field ('fieldA') that can contain either a string or an array of strings. Actually, I'd prefer it only ever contain strings, but the elasticsearch mapping doesn't work that way. Anyway, now I need to find every document where this field is an array. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" :{
                "script" : {
                    "script" : "_source.fieldA.getClass() != String"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had to turn on a particular Elasticsearch setting to use the script in a newer version of Elasticsearch.

```
script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on
```

Here is the script I ran to create a sample index and try that out:

```
curl -w "\n" -XDELETE localhost:9200/scrap

curl -w "\n" -XPUT localhost:9200/scrap/ -d '
index :
    number_of_replicas : 0
'

curl -w "\n" -XPUT localhost:9200/scrap/script-demo/1?refresh=1 -d '{
    "fieldA" : "test string 1"
}'

curl -w "\n" -XPUT localhost:9200/scrap/script-demo/2?refresh=1 -d '{
    "fieldA" : [
        "test string 1",
        "test string 2"
    ]
}'

curl -w "\n" -XPUT localhost:9200/scrap/script-demo/3?refresh=1 -d '{
    "fieldA" : [
        "test string 1"
    ]
}'

curl -w "\n" -XPOST localhost:9200/scrap/script-demo/_search -d '{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" :{
                "script" : {
                    "script" : "_source.fieldA.getClass() != String"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}' | python -m json.tool

# curl -w "\n" -XDELETE localhost:9200/scrap
```

Of course, I am making assumptions about the analyzer you might have on the field and details like that might come into play.

Here are some resources on scripts:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-script-filter.html

It looks like the script filter was replaced in v2.0.

Comment: While I'm at it, do you know why scripts sometimes use doc[<field>], ctx._source, and other times just _source? I can't seem to find any clues in the docs about that.

Comment: Check out the doc on [script fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html).  I only see ctx._source for the [scripted updates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html#_using_scripts_to_make_partial_updates).  I wonder if that is the only place that is appropriate...  sorry, not sure about that :( Good question... I never wondered about that till now.